# JQuery element refering to itself inside chain

Tags: jquery

How can I refer to current jquery element
during a collection iteraction
inside a method chain

```
$('a')
    .attr( 'text', <GET_SELF_HERE>.text() + "any text" )
    .click();
```

I thought there was something like $.self() or $('self') to solve this
$(this) do not resolve the case (returns undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with many other jQuery methods (`.css()`, `.offset()` etc.), you can supply a function as a second param for `attr` method. This function will be called as many times as there are elements wrapped in jQuery object; the context of each call (in other words, `this`) will be the DOM element processed in this particular call. So this is one possible approach:

```
$('a')
  .attr('data-text', function() {
    return $(this).text() + 'any text';
  });
```

And if you really want to change the *text* of the link, use [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) (again, with a function param) instead:

```
$('a')
  .text(function(_, text) { 
    return text + 'some text'; 
  });
```

Comment: yep... that works... and you can even avoid the $(this) to ''jquerize the object'' and use 'this.text' (the raw JS/DOM object)... but I think there should be already a simplified jquery solution,,, this pattern occurs regularly... a $.self() maybe ??? or to stay in JS taxonomy a $.this()...

Comment: It _is_ a simplified pattern. You seem to miss one thing: an `attr` param, whatever it'll be, will only be evaluated _once_. The best you can do is with some function - but then again, there's already a way to do exactly that with a function param.

Comment: As for `this.text` - there's no such property actually. But yes, you can go with `this.textContent` - unless you're a poor soul designing a solution that has to be compatible with IE8. )

Comment: 'textContent' from the raw DOM element was what I meant... thanks for your insights ;)